# How to remove hash from images with webpack 5

Tags: webpack

I have some problem with image management with webpack 5. I try to use "type" option to handle images for my project.
It works when I'm only using [hash] and [ext], but not works when i replace [hash] with [name].

Here is my working current Webpack 5 configuration for images :

```
// webpack.config.js
// Images Files Management
const imgConfig = {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|ico)$/i,
    type: "asset/resource",
    generator: {
        filename: 'assets/img/[hash][ext][query]'
    }
}
```

I want to remove hash and only have original image name and not hash, so I tried something like this, but the build stoped and can't be completed.

```
// webpack.config.js
// Images Files Management
const imgConfig = {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|ico)$/i,
    type: "asset/resource",
    generator: {
        filename: 'assets/img/[name][ext]'
    }
}
```

Is it possible with webpack 5 ?

Here is my configuration :

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
    ...
}
```

EDIT: It's seems that only **png** files causing crash when building, other image formats like jpeg, jpg, svg, webp are working well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68814833/webpack-5-assets-module-how-to-keep-the-folder-structure-in-the-output-folder) one?
It looks like the property `assetModuleFilename` does what you need.